# unable to retrive data in crud operation

Tags: django

```
{%for x in read%}
{%if request.user == user%}
<div class="card " >
    <h5>
    <div class="card-header bg-info">
      Dr.{{i.name}}
    </div>
    </h5>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h6 class="card-title ">Appointment Date : {{x.appoinment_date}}</h6>
      <h6 class="card-title">Age : {{x.age}}</h6>
      <h6 class="card-title">Digree : {{x.disease}}</h6>
      <h6 class="card-title">Email : {{x.email}}</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
{%endif%}
{%endfor%}
```

i am using code above but i am getting data of all users instead of current user

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your application, but it seems like the if-statement relates to some variable 'user', while in the table everything relates to 'x.something'. If what you're trying to do is filter for rows that are only related to the current user, you may want to check

```
{%if request.user == x.user%}
```